# How to compare datas from sensor in python?

Tags: python, arrays, raspberry-pi, sensors

I'm using HC-SR04 sensor on raspberry pi and I want to compare the datas I have read. When I tried to store the datas in an array it just store one of them and it updates itself constantly. How can I store all of them or compare one data to another?

```
distance = (pulse_duration * 34320)*0.5
distance = round(distance,2)
array = []
array.append(distance)
```

output of this code is:

```
distance: 10.7cm
array: [10.7]
distance: 10.63cm
array: [10.63]
```

Comment: `array = []` is this in a loop? This will recreate the array each time. Only call this once, maybe at the start of the program.

Comment: put those on a fixed size `queue`, and `pop` the last two, and do some comparison /

Comment: Thank you, that solved my array problem. If I don't want to use an array how can I compare the datas I get from sensor?

Comment: My suggestion is to put into a database and from there compute de data historical data maybe useful for some other project.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I haven't watched this yet  but Pycon videos are often informative - [Working with real-time data streams in Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFeTkB8VHpw)

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue of array-recreation is fixed by initializing your array outside of the loop that code resides in. However, for data analysis, I would suggest placing these values into a [numpy array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) or a [pandas Series/DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). This will allow you to perform quick (and low time complexity) analysis on frequent sensor data. For example, instead of:

```
array = []
sum = 0
for i in array:
    sum += i
mean = sum / len(array)
```

You can use the C optimized numpy function:

```
np.mean(sensor_matrix)
```